# Mutex Locks vs Peterson's Algorithm?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, operating-system, locking

Do mutex locks ensure bounded waiting condition ? Is it possible if two threads are trying to get hold of a lock, but only one process (just by luck) gets it again and again. Since Peterson's Algorithm ensures bounded waiting, is it better to use that instead of mutex locks ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have unbounded wait with mutices, if for instance locking attempts keep coming in on a mutex, at least in C++ std::mutex there's no guaranteed first comes first gets.

However this shouldn't really be a concern - Unless you have some lock with many many threads locking all the time (and even in that case it's very unlikely to cause some starvation situation).

The best thing to do is always use standard library locking mechanism and not write your own mutices.

Answer (score 2):

Mutex with "bounded waiting condition" is called Fair sometimes. As gbehar correctly mention above, C++ standard doesn't define fairness for std::mutex. If you really need fair mutex, you can look at Intel TBB, where fairness is guaranteed for some kinds of them. I would like to remember that fairness comes not without overhead.

See https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/Mutex_Flavors.html for details.

Update: Current link https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/blob/master/doc/main/tbb_userguide/Mutex_Flavors.rst